# Get a module version for a list of modules

Tags: 7, drush

### Context

- Drush version 8.x
- Drupal 7 site

### Problem

- Mr. HtraenuRekaos has a text file with a list of Drupal contrib modules.
- He wants to get the recommended-install version of all the modules in the list.
- This list is not associated with any pre-existing site, and none of the modules are currently installed.

### Non-solutions

- Mr. H has already looked at this SO post: [Using wget to get the latest module version](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15859/using-wget-to-get-the-latest-module-version), but he does not want to use wget, he wants to use drush
- Mr. H does not want to actually *download or install* the relevant modules, he only wants to get a list with the latest recommended D7.x version.

### Question(s)

- Is there a drush command that will turn *before* into *after*?

#### Before

`MODULE_NAME_HERE    ;; RECCO_VERSION_HERE
contrib_module_001   ;;   __blank__
foobar_module        ;;   __blank__
htraenurekaos        ;;   __blank__`

#### After

`MODULE_NAME_HERE    ;; RECCO_VERSION_HERE
contrib_module_001   ;;   7.x-1.6
foobar_module        ;;   7.x-2.2
htraenurekaos        ;;   7.x-3.6`

Comment: Drush will always download the "Recommended" latest version. So why bother keeping track of the actual version numbers?

Comment: @NoSssweat: because he wants to have a record for use with a git-tracked drush makefile.

Comment: In your make file, you could use put `version: ~` so it automatically downloads the latest version. If you put `version: '1.2'` it will always download 7.x-1.2 even if a new version  7.x-1.3 is out.

Comment: @NoSssweat: and if that newer version of the module has a regression or incompatibility with any other module on the site, you've got a potentially broken site.

Comment: true, but what if the newer version has a security or bug fix or adds a new awesome feature? I guess its a trade off.

Comment: @NoSssweat: except you don't have a record of which specific version broke your site if you have `~` everywhere, nothing gets tracked in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mr. H does not want to actually download or install the relevant modules, he only wants to get a list with the latest recommended D7.x version.

Well, at the very least, you can do:

`drush @site.env up module_name --select` for individual modules, you can also do:

`drush @site.env pm-releases` which has a load of options for output.

https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/pm/pm-releases/

It has format options.

Comment: Just in case anyone is following along: `drush pm-releases module_name_here --format=yaml` does the trick. You have to crawl through the YAML though, and pull out the `status` key, and search for `Recommended`.

Comment: I don't see any reason to go through YAML. Just use awk and the normal (table) output from Drush: ```drush pm-releases some_module | grep Recommended | awk '{print $2}'``` will return the version number.

Comment: @hansfn **//I don't see any reason//** -- having a structured data format such as JSON or YAML obviates the need to write one-off parsers or shell scripts, for those who wish to avoid the potentially brittle and easily-broken (and usually under-documented) "screen scraping" approach offered by tools such as awk, perl, and grep. **not everyone will agree with this, but it is a reason**